# Why are identical objects from snapshot.before and snapshot.after, not equal?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, javascript-objects, snapshot

I have a cloud function to increment a counter, only if certain fields change within the snapshot ('exercises' in this case).

In my cloud function, I have this check that always fires for some reason:

```
const before = snapshot.before.data();
const after = snapshot.after.data();     
if (before['exercises'] !== after['exercises']) {
   console.log(before['exercises']);
   console.log(after['exercises']);
   // Increment the counter...
}
```

And the log statements are identical:

```
[ { exerciseId: '-LZ7UD7VR7ydveVxqzjb',
    title: 'Barbell Bench Press' } ] // List of exercise objects

[ { exerciseId: '-LZ7UD7VR7ydveVxqzjb',
    title: 'Barbell Bench Press' } ] // Same list of exercise objects
```

What can I do to ensure that these values within the snapshot get treated as equal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript an object is a reference type. If you make this:

```
{a: 1} === {a: 1}
```

It will be false because Javascript is reading:

`ObjectReference1 === ObjectReference2`

There are things you can to for [determine the equality of two Javascript Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects) but if your object is that little I would just do a `JSON.stringify` equality

```js
const before = {
  exerciseId: '-LZ7UD7VR7ydveVxqzjb',
    title: 'Barbell Bench Press' }

const after = {
  exerciseId: '-LZ7UD7VR7ydveVxqzjb',
  title: 'Barbell Bench Press'
};

function areEqual(object1, object2) {
  return JSON.stringify(object1) === JSON.stringify(object2);
}


console.log(areEqual(before, after)); /// true
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed :)